# How to implement One shot Help in Alexa using alexa skills kit in nodejs?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am developing custom Alexa Skill using NodeJs. I got the following message from the certification team

Issue: **One-shot help is not working**.
Pre-conditions – 1) Have enabled the skill "xyz".

Steps to reproduce:

Launch the Skill in one shot by saying "Alexa, ask xyz for help" and observe.

**Actual result**

Skill responds as "I did not understand what you said. Please say again."

**Expected result**:

The skill should be able to give help prompt in one shot utterance just the way it would give in the modal request saying  "The skill helps bla bla bla (my help message when the user says help while using the skill)"

As per the documentation of One-Shot

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing-for-a-custom-skill.html#46-one-shot-phrasing-for-sample-utterances

I did not find any sample implementation at their Github repository. How do I implement one-shot help as required by the certification team?

Comment: Using Alexa Test simulator check your generated JSON request for one shot help call "Alexa, ask xyz for help". Check the intent triggered.

Comment: (Rather than asking what code to show, please show what you think would be a good start, and trust that people will ask for more if they need it. Questions are posted here for perpetuity, and we don't want old questions to contain redundant enquiries about what code readers wish to see. Thanks!)

Comment: It triggers `Amazon.HelpIntent` 

`  { ... "request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.1e96a6aa-ced2-418e-8f2a-f2fba850e92e",
  "timestamp": "2018-09-20T09:02:15Z",
  "locale": "en-IN",
  "intent": {
   "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
   "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
  }
 }
}
`

Interestingly HelpIntent is already handled in the code

Comment: Can you check your schema and confirm which locale has got 'Amazon.HelpIntent' intent .I faced similar situation and it turn out to be that intent was added in en-GB locale but not on en-AU locale and the device which we were testing was registered in en-AU region.

Comment: @CicilThomas Thanks for your input I was able to figure out what the problem was. When using one-shot for Help, STATE was not getting initialized, which caused the skill to break.

Comment: @user398707 Thanks for the clue. I figured out the issue by investigating the Request Json from the simulator and using Cloud Watch to debug the skill